# Angular 8 : How to send the value from *ngfor to TS file

Tags: angular, angular8, ngfor

I have a code

```
<div *ngFor="let a of ABC">
{{a.error}}
</div>
```

Now I want to send the value of a to my TS file. I want to meet some expectation say 'a.error == true' then call some function and assign the value of a to some variable in ts file.

I hope it is clear. please ask if require more clarification

Comment: your ts file already has all the values in that array contained in the ABC array. so it doesn't really make sense to ask "how do I send the value". All the values already exist.

Comment: If I understand, you want to define in your template that a function should be executed in some condition. Well, it may be possible but please, never do it ...

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with the ts file as you say you just call a function which you declare

```
// In your ts.file

someFunction(a: any) {
  // some amazing stuff
  return 'Hello World';
}
```

and in your template

```
<div *ngFor="let a of ABC">
  {{ someFunction(a) }}
</div>
```

Comment: I want to send the value of a without showing it on UI

Comment: Why don't you just do that when you fetch it in `ngOnInit` then?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably loop the variable `ABC` in the TS file before exposing it to the html template. Be aware of the fact that. if you call a function in the html, it will be evaluated many many times.

e.g. , the following will execute the `someFunction` many more times than you probably need.

```
//.html
<div *ngFor="let a of ABC">
{{someFunction(a)}}
</div>
```

I suggest creating the values you need to read in the html as a different var.
for example.

```
//.ts
ERR: string[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.ERR = ABC.map(a => someFunction(a));
}
```

Then in the template just bind to the error array

```
//.html
<div *ngFor="let a of ERR">
    {{a}}
</div>
```